# When forgetting to add tags in a meta question, the website isn't as helpful as it should be

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions

I asked a question over at meta.askubuntu.com. It went something like this:

- Wrote question, clicked on submit.
- **You forgot to use tags, please use tags.**
- Added tag *design*, clicked on submit.
- Solved captcha.
- **You have to add one of those tags: bug, feature-request, discussion.**
- Added tag *feature-request*, clicked on submit.
- Solved captcha.

Is it possible to only ask for the captcha if the question is valid, e.g. has tags filled out correctly?

Please tell me the first time that I have to use one of the required tags.

Comment: +1 a rather minor detail, but a bump in SO's otherwise smooth user experience.

Comment: Eh, you get used to it. I'm on Meta too much -- every time I want to ask a question on SO, I instinctively type `[bug]` into the tags field. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This no longer happens, as we now check for post submission validity *before* allowing the Captcha to occur.

Verified on meta.askubuntu.com

Comment: Are you saying this is the case on other 'meta' sites than this one? I just had pretty much the exact same experience as the OP.

Comment: @daniel I can't repro -- we check validity before invoking captcha. However, be aware that VERY FAST (< 5 seconds between) actions will always trigger bot detection.